# Pandas set multiple column and row values to nan based on another dataframe with different column headers

Tags: pandas, dataframe, python-3.8

I have two large dataframes, `df1`:

```
Col1    Col2    Val1    Val2    Val3
asd     ASYL    4.2             4.2
ppq     CONE            35      35
DA      HU      100     100
```

And `df2` is

```
Col1    Col2    PR1     PR2   PR3
asd     ASYL    7       12    17
ppq     CONE    17      19    19
DA      HU      5       14    13
```

Both dataframes have same index columns `Col1` and `Col2` and but different columns `Val1, Val2, Val3` in `df1` and `PR1, PR2, PR3` in `df2`.

The order of relevance for columns in `df2` is same for my purposes however.

I want to set the values in `df2` to `nan` where it is `Null` in `df1` to get the following:

```
Col1    Col2    PR1     PR2   PR3
asd     ASYL    7             17
ppq     CONE            19    19
DA      HU      5       14
```

I tried the following:

```
df2.where(df1.notna())
```

But it is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the order of relevance of columns in both `df1` and `df2` is same, Use, [`df.mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) along with [`df.set_axis`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_axis.html) and [`df.isna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isna.html):

```
df2 = df2.mask(df1.set_axis(df2.columns, 1).isna())
```

---

```
# print(df2)

           PR1   PR2   PR3
Col1 Col2                 
asd  ASYL  7.0   NaN  17.0
ppq  CONE  NaN  19.0  19.0
DA   HU    5.0  14.0   NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

Didn't I just answer this question

```
df1.mask(df1.notna(),df2)
```

[image]

Comment: Those previous answers don't preserve the column and index definitions. Yes I can do multi-steps to get to answers but I was looking for cool python way of it when the column headers are different :)